# Rollback transaction does not decrements auto incremented column?

Tags: sql, t-sql, auto-increment, decrement

**T-SQL:**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

Insert (col1,col2,col3)

values (1,2,3)
```

After executing above t-sql and then `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`  MS-SQL does not decrements auto incremented column. Any idea why?

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758625/mysql-auto-increment-columns-on-transaction-commit-and-rollback). Is this answer is applicable to MS-SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, SQL server will not "re-use" identity numbers once assigned. What's more, it is not guaranteed that the values will be [consecutive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property):

> Consecutive values within a transaction – A transaction inserting
>   multiple rows is not guaranteed to get consecutive values for the rows
>   because other concurrent inserts might occur on the table. If values
>   must be consecutive then the transaction should use an exclusive lock
>   on the table or use the SERIALIZABLE isolation level.

You can use [DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql) to change the identity values, but it is best to treat them as unique system IDs and do not assume anything about order.

You may also want to look at SEQUENCE which has some advantages over IDENTITY.

Comment: any idea - what is the best practice to insert rows to live database table?

Comment: that would depend on the scenario. There are ETL tools for batch inserts (e.g. SSIS). Apps can use entity framework, OLE DB, JDBC... Best to ask a separate question and be more specific.