# Laravel transaction rollback

Tags: mysql

The issue with laravel rollback, that the id is always incremented even the multiple insertion in the DB is failed.

For example, i am using laravel transaction to insert two models.
The model 1 latest id is 5, and the model 2 latest id is 10, when the normal  tranaction start, the result will be that the inserted object from model 1 is 6 and for the model 2 is 11.

For the second insertion, the model 1 is inserted and the new id is 7, but the model 2 insertion is failed, so it will rollback, but the next insertion for model 1 will be 9 and not 8 even it is failed.

Ok, the problem is that the id in the DB(Mysql, engine innoDB) is incremented, but it must be a solution when it is rolledback the id too.

Does any one have any idea how to resolve this issue ? Thank you.

Comment: Why is that an issue?

Comment: If there is an exception in the insertion, it will be written in the log file, so there is no need to jump  a value of the id in the DB(which is big).

Comment: This is default database behavior and not laravel specific, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449387/9193055) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14758690/9193055) should answer your question.

Comment: Thank you @Remul, it was helpful. The idea is clear, it is a default database behavior.