# jdbc 4 connection rollback autoincrement issue

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I just started learning jdbc and doing various tests with it.

I came across the following situation

- set savepoint
- create prepared statement and try to execute(insert data into a table with foreign key value that doesn't exist
- the execute() method fails and I do a rollback.
- when  I do a valid query a row is inserted into the db, but the primary key is set as n+2 instead of n+1(where n is the last inserted value). Guess the index autoincrements even though the query fails.

Is there a mechanism to avoid this and set n+1?

Note. I am using MySQL.

Thanks.

Comment: how about reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449346/mysql-auto-increment-does-not-rollback topic?

Comment: I agree with that post, but I don't want to take into consideration that in my app logic. I was just wondering why the phenomenon is happening and if there's a way to overcome this.

Comment: It happens because the id generation is independent of the transaction. There is no way to overcome it without a lot of effort. Don't assign any meaning to the id.

Comment: And this is why Oracle databases don't have AUTO_INCREMENT fields. Use a trigger instead.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is normal for MySQL auto_increment.
Well, you can do some magic using mysql_insert_id().