# auto_increment value increments even if an exception DUPLICATE KEY is thrown or the transaction is Rolled back

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a table - with `id` which is `auto_increment` and a `email` column which is defined to be `UNIQUE`.

Consider the `auto_increment` to be set to 1.

In my `stored procedure` when I `INSERT` a new row with a unique email id the auto_increment column is incremented. Correct behavior.

Now when I try to `INSERT` the same email again `UNIQUE KEY` is violated. I check this and do a `ROLLBACK`. However the auto_increment is set to 2 now. **Why?**

In the third attempt of `INSERT`, this time with a unique email the row is inserted however the `id` field has value 3. Not good.

Is there a way I can decrement the value back to 2.

Comment: There is a way and you don't want to do it because you'll violate your data integrity. "Wasted" auto_increments are fine. Their purpose is not to give you pretty sequential numbers. Use triggers if you need that and create a procedure that'll use another column which'll provide that functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this: [MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT does not ROLLBACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449346/mysql-auto-increment-does-not-rollback)

The most salient point being: **You should never depend on the numeric features of autogenerated keys.**