# the AUTO_INCREMENT field is not rollbacked, when rollback is not called

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions

I'm using MySQL's AUTO_INCREMENT field and InnoDB to support transactions. I noticed when I rollback the transaction, the AUTO_INCREMENT field is not rollbacked?
But when I don't call RollBack the id doesn't change.

```
try
{

//My Code
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
    //deadlock exception in mysql   
    if (ex.Number == 1213)
    {
        //I don't use RollBack and the id dosen't change
        MessageBox.Show("Try again", "Warning");
    }
    else
    {
        msqlTr.Rollback();
        txtError.Text = "Erreur : " + ex.Message;
        Log.LogError.setError(ex);
        MessageBox.Show("Erreur : " + ex.Message, "Erreur", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    msqlTr.Rollback();
    txtError.Text = "Erreur : " + ex.Message;
    Log.LogError.setError(ex);
    MessageBox.Show("Erreur : " + ex.Message, "Erreur", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

If this code correct, I mean that when I don't call rollback?

Answer (score 0):

The Identity Increment happens outside of the transaction.  That is working as expected.

[MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT does not ROLLBACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449346/mysql-auto-increment-does-not-rollback)