# Spring boot 1.4 test with h2database (rollback in each test)

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot, h2

I'm new on testing and I'm running a @DataJpaTest (spring boot 1.4).
I have some tests running right but I want all the tests perform a rollback before start an other to avoid h2database errors or conflicts.

I'm using a general "import.sql" file to insert some common data at startup and I'm doing some inserts in each test.

Thank you

Comment: Post some code and also your observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mark your test classes with `@Transactional` in order to make them rollback automatically after each test.

Comment: Thank you Vsevolod.
Debugging I saw that the problem was not the conflicts (rollback is ok), but the sequence (id) is increased in each test.
How can I fix that?

Comment: @MarcosVidoli, why do you care about indices? Look here, please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449346/mysql-auto-increment-does-not-rollback