# Auto Increment ID Roll back in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to Rollback or Reset Auto Increment ID from multiple mysql tables after Transaction Fail in Laravel 5.6.

```
DB::beginTransaction();
 try {

  //My Database Queries goes here

  DB::commit();
 }

catch (\Exception $e) {

       DB::rollback();
     }
```

Simply what I want is, I want to write some Query to Rollback Auto Increment IDs here

```
catch (\Exception $e) {

   DB::rollback();
 }
```

after `DB::rollback()` executed.

Can any body suggest me a way to do that..?

Answer (score 0):

To strictly answer your question, I think you should first find your max for the AI column (e.g. named id)

SQL:

```
  SELECT MAX(id) FROM yourTable;
```

in Laravel

```
  $maxId = DB::table('yourTable')->max('id');
```

Then reset Auto Increment value:

SQL:

```
  ALTER TABLE yourTable AUTO_INCREMENT=$maxId;
```

in Laravel

```
 DB::statement("ALTER TABLE yourTable AUTO_INCREMENT=$maxId");
```

In any case I would be careful in what you're doing.
Just in case you think to rely on your AI id column....Have a look at this: [MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT does not ROLLBACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449346/mysql-auto-increment-does-not-rollback)

Otherwise if it's just a worry to not grow big with id values because you've got thousands of failing Transactions... it might be an optimisation.But in this case I would get rid of id column at all...