# Laravel MYSQL if DB::commit not added skips id and when added takes subsequent one

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6.2

I am working with Laravel Transactions. I came across a weird thing can anyone help me out to explain the same.

I start **DB::transaction()** in my base controller construct like the following

### Controller.php

```
public function __construct(){
    DB::transaction();
}
```

This will be used in any other controller functions as follows

```
class ProductsController extends Controller{
    function testing(){
        try{
            //Code which works
            if(//notworks){
                throw new Exception('Yo! Something fucked up');
            }

            DB::commit();
        }catch(Exception $e){
            DB::rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

For the first time, I omitted the **DB::commit** and then the very next time I added it. Instead of having id as 1 it added 2. Again I retested the same with same steps so instead of 3 it added 4

As per my knowledge that row is locked or something.

What exactly is happening? Any help on the same will be really appreciated.

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: @Strawberry no it doesn't. But it would be good if I understand what actually is going on.

Comment: check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449346/mysql-auto-increment-does-not-rollback) question.