# MySQL id not saving in order (Laravel in production)

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, heroku, cleardb

[image]

Hi guys! I'm really confused about this..

So, I created a Laravel app and hosted it on Heroku. I'm using ClearDB extension to be able to use MySQL. Problem is: when I save a new User on my DB, it is not being saved in ID order.

I got id 1, then id 11 for the second register, then id 21 for the third...
Then I deleted them and tried again, and I got id 31. I think, there's a pattern, huh? It's going +10, +10... But why?

Look, the code I'm using to save a new register is only: `DB::table('registers')->insert($registerData);`

On the $registerData variable, I have only the following data: name, e-mail, a url for the picture and birth date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create record in transaction and rollback it (because exception maybe), the auto-incremented value will be skipped.

Check application logs. And add migration code and action code to your question.

After deleting all the rows and creating new one you will took `ID = LAST_DELETED_ROW_ID + 1` because MySQL stores increment counter in table meta (see this question: [How to reset AUTO_INCREMENT in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql)).

Helpful answer:
[MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT does not ROLLBACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449346/mysql-auto-increment-does-not-rollback/449360#449360)

Comment: I found at cleardb documentation that they use the default auto_increment set to 10. So the numbers really go like 1, 11, 21... They say it's to prevent "potential key collisions". Thx! :)